# Can't connect to AWS Cloudfront using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudfront, connection-timeout

I have a Lambda function that tries to invalidate the cache of a Cloudfront distribution, but it times out. The same function succesfully connects to SecretsManager.

```py
# python code

session = boto3.session.Session()

# ....

cf_client = session.client(service_name='cloudfront', config=config)

# ......

cf_client.create_invalidation(
          DistributionId=distro,
          InvalidationBatch={
              'Paths': {
                  'Quantity': 1,
                  'Items': [f'/api/dict/{dict_name}/article/{art_id}']
              },
              'CallerReference': str(time.time())
          }
      )
```

I'm using this policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "cloudfront:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm aware that S3 and SecretsManager require certain endpoints in VPC to be set up, is there something similar for Cloudfront?

Comment: From where are you running this code? For example, is it from your own computer, from an AWS Lambda function, or from an Amazon EC2 instance (and is it in a public or private subnet)?

Comment: It's a Lambda function with private subnets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there something similar for Cloudfront?

No there is not. CloudFront [does not have](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/integrated-services-vpce-list.html) VPC interface endpoint. You have to setup NAT to interact with CF from private subnets. Alternatively, you can do it indirectly through lambda functions, which have VPC interface endpoint.

Comment: Rather than setting up a NAT gateway, I tested it from a Lambda with no VPC, and it worked. My solution will probably be to use a specialised, non-VPC Lambda for cache invalidation.